# Migrate ASP.NET app on .net 4.5 to ASP.NET v5 - docs? concepts?

Tags: asp.net, .net

Like a lot of us, we are really looking forward to ASP.NET v5. Being able to self host, without IIS, is huuuuge.

Our app includes portions on ASP.NET 4.x ("classic" asp.net, without mvc), and also chunks of the site that use MVC v2 and v3.

As we look at the state of ASP.NET v5, it looks to be a big lift to move an app up from ASP.NET 4.x.

From the docs on the [asp.net site](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/index.html) , there is no mention of how to take an existing ASP.NET app and move it to v5.

But, reading those same docs, v5 is a biiiig delta from asp.net to date. It would seem there is no way that stuff is "just going to work."

What is the best way to approach a migration?

Comment: There is no such thing as ASP.NET Classic. And asking us to recommend off site resources such as docs or tools to perform your migration is not allowed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @mason OP enhanced. Hopefully in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET is base framework and MVC is extension to it. So MS promots it as ASP.NET MVC x.
If you are talking about ASP.NET 4.x classic do it mean ASP.NET Web Forms, like used  Page events to build a web application?

If that is the case then you first refer these articles it will really help - [Strategy considerations when migrating ASP.NET forms to MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/754763/Strategy-considerations-when-migrating-ASP-NET-for) and 
[ASP.NET WebForms and ASP.NET MVC in Harmony](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38778/ASP-NET-WebForms-and-ASP-NET-MVC-in-Harmony)